# How can I find some objects in game?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I want to find some objects(TownHall, Collectors, etc..) in ClashOfClans.
I tried to use OpenCV. I create template for finding TownHall. 
[template.bmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZS9AU.png)
Code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy
from matplotlib import  pyplot as plt
img = cv.imread('screen_4.jpg',0)
img2 = img.copy()

template = cv.imread('temp_2.bmp',0)
w, h  = template.shape[::-1]


methods = ['cv.TM_CCOEFF', 'cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED', 'cv.TM_CCORR',
        'cv.TM_CCORR_NORMED', 'cv.TM_SQDIFF', 'cv.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED']

for meth in methods:
    img = img2.copy()
    method = eval(meth)

    rev = cv.matchTemplate(img, template, method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(rev)

    if method in [cv.TM_SQDIFF, cv.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]:
        top_left = min_loc
    else:
        top_left = max_loc

    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)

    cv.rectangle(img, top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)

    print(top_left, bottom_right)

    plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(rev, cmap='gray')
    plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    plt.title('Detected Point'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.suptitle(meth)
    plt.show()
```

But I have unstable results. But for one picture it works, but not for the other. What can you offer? How can I recognize objects in a screenshot by template?

Comment: Why are you using eval? Just take the qoutes off the strings in the list and take eval line out

Comment: @Jab but I need to print method name. plt.suptitle(meth)